# Is there a way to reduce the complexity of this program?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

the problem is as follows:
Consider a table with 1 column as follows:

1. a,b
2. b,c
3. a,c
4. a,b,d
5. ...

I have to find a list of elements such that exactly 1 element of the list is present in every row of the table.

The only way I can think of a creating every possible subset and check if 1 of the subset satisfies the condition

Comment: The solution can also be `[a, c]`?

Comment: None of the letters in your example is all the lines. So the answer should [a, b, c, d]?

Comment: @nice_dev yes [a,c ] can also be a potential solution .

Comment: @paul sinnema  I have mentioned that exactly 1 of the elemt in the list should be in all the rows. in [a,b,c,d] both a and b is present in the first row which is wrong.

Comment: `[b,c]` is not a solution because it fails the "exactly one element" requirement (same thing with `[a,c]`).

Comment: Are you allowed to assume advance knowledge of the possible elements, or at least the number of such elements? Are you allowed to assume advance knowledge of the number of rows? For example, can we assume in your example that the possible elements are the one-characters strings `a`..`z`, and the total number of rows is (let's say) 73? Or do you have to be able to account for arbitrary elements and arbitrary numbers of rows as you go?

Comment: @ n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m You are right. Editing the question now

Comment: @Dan lenski. there is a finite number of rows( say 5000 rows)  with each row containing a finite number of elements. (say 10 elements)

Comment: @AMITESHkumar, are those finite numbers _known in advance_?

Comment: This is akin to the [Set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) which is NP hard.

Comment: @Dan Lenski  Yes

Comment: If the table contains ((a,b),(b,c),(a,c)), there is no solution.

Comment: @trincot It doesn't resemble set-cover at all.  Set-cover asks to find the smallest set of subsets that covers the universe. This problem asks to find some set of elements that covers the universe and intersects with each subset at exactly one element.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., I know that. I used the word "akin", as [*"...having some of the same qualities..."*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/akin)

Comment: "Every possible subset" is an overkill. If `a` is in the subset, then a letter that is together with `a` in any of the rows can't be. Moreover, for a row that has N letters, exactly one of them must be in the subset (out of 2^N possible combinations). This should be fast enough to solve with some backtracking. Pick the longest row, try each letter in it. For each letter *k* you try, go through all rows, find all letters that are present in the same row with *k*, and eliminate them. Then go to the next row. If you find an uncovered empty row, the candidate is bad, so backtrack.